# JaVers: Hibernate integration WITHOUT Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, javers

I'm currently working on a project for which we need to track changes to model objects. We would like to use JaVers for that, as it seems exactly what we need for. However, for some reason, the client forbids the use of Spring.
Is it possible to integrate JaVers and Hibernate together, without Spring librairies ?

Thanks

Edit: Actually, the project use JPA 2 for persistence, with Hibernate implementation (JBOSS server)

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, JaVers Core doesn't depend on Spring nor Hibernate.
There is no special Hibernate support in JaVers, but you can use JaVers directly, take a look at these examples:

http://javers.org/documentation/repository-examples/#commit-changes

http://javers.org/documentation/repository-configuration/#choose-javers-repository

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that my entities have a lot a associations which are lazy loaded, with transactions managed by JPA...In your opinion, would it be managable to adapt JaVers-Spring layer to make it work with JPA only?

Comment: Why not? Remember to register HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook, see http://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#jpa-entity-manager-integration

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work with HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook indeed. I still have a problem with Hibernate lazy collections but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has nothing to do with Spring. All Spring provides is a helpful way to lookup and wire datasource to Hibernate, create/manage Hibernate sessions and transactions.
Without spring you have to do all of it right in your code unless Javers can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a hibernate.xml file which housse just the hibernate configuration. Then you're going to want to load that configuration and use it to create a sessionFactory and from there you can create a session and do all that good stuff. Here's a link on how to get started:

https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The persistence layer of the project is already set up. I just need to make JaVers work with it.

Comment: Could you solve it? If so, would you share how you set it up? I also facing with the issue using javers as audit without any spring dependencies